# Live Agent Chat - Unable to establish with custom chat window

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have set up live chat in my dev org and am able to conduct a session without problem.  However,  when I use a custom chat page,  no connection is made and the page just hangs at the point of connecting to an agent.

I'm seeing the **following error** in the console, which might be the cause - I'm not sure:

> Uncaught Error: Organization ID must be set!
>   window.liveagent.chasitor.init @ chasitor.js:70 Sfdc.provide.init @
>   LiveAgentChatWindow.js:24 (anonymous function) @
>   LiveAgentCustomChat?language=&core.apexpages.devmode.url=1:148

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of a conflict with the developer mode being turned On for the user.